# CLI to get Xcode Crash Reports

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight, fastlane

I often check the crash reports collected by Apple via Window -> Organizer -> Crashes. This is a really nice feature but it often gives me a "unable to download crash information"-alert.
So, my question is: in times of https://fastlane.tools/, is there some comparable CLI to obtain Crash Reports?